# PhpStorm doesn't see any android devices

Tags: react-native, phpstorm

Now command `npx react-native run-android` work in Windows command line, but when I try call it in PhpStorm Terminal:

```
"adb" ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп ў­гваҐ­­Ґ© Ё«Ё ў­Ґи­Ґ©
Є®¬ ­¤®©, ЁбЇ®«­пҐ¬®© Їа®Ја ¬¬®© Ё«Ё Ї ЄҐв­л¬ д ©«®¬.
info Launching emulator...
info Installing the app...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
```

Before I reinstalled Windows, it worked fine. I don't understand what I forgot to configure. Where could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just reinstall IDE and problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's too late but it may still help others.

> "adb" ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп ў­гваҐ­­Ґ© Ё«Ё ў­Ґи­Ґ©
> Є®¬ ­¤®©, ЁбЇ®«­пҐ¬®© Їа®Ја ¬¬®© Ё«Ё Ї ЄҐв­л¬ д ©«®¬.

Is actually a Russian equivalent of

> 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

affected by some encoding issues.

It means that you need to add the path to your `adb` file to the System PATH variable and then restart the IDE.

`adb` should be located in the `platform-tools` folder of your android SDK.